# When to release UserControl event handlers?

Tags: wpf, events, user-controls, dispose

If I'm registering events on a UserControl in the code behind. E.g.:

```
public partial class PositionView : UserControl
{
    // If required ViewModel can be accessed using DataContext 
    public PositionViewModel ViewModel 
    {
        get { return (PositionViewModel) this.DataContext; }
    }

    public PositionView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContextChanged += new System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(PositionView_DataContextChanged);
    }

    void PositionView_DataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.UpdateTotalsChanged.Subscribe(_ => this.PositionGridControl.UpdateTotalSummary());
    }       
}
```

When should I be disposing of the event handler? There is no IDisposable to hook onto?

If I bind to the event via the xaml will this be a cleaner solution in terms of lifetime management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the `Event` as well as the `EventHandler` are local. Therefore they will be collected when the `UserControl` itself is collected.

When the `UserControl` is collected there will be no other object that is keeping your eventHandler  alive. Therefore you do not need to manually implement 'lifetime management'.

Comment: Ok but in the more general case where I might be hooking onto a keyboard event etc? i.e. when I don't want to rely on local scoping.

Comment: I doubt an UserControl should bind to events outside of its scope as it is supposed to be a (databound) unit.   Keyboard events actually are fired on the user control so you can handle those in private scope as well.